# HQL : Order by varchar2 as INT

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, hql

I'm working on a statement in HQL and I would like to have results sorted by numbers.

Kind of results I can have :
DR71 Frein
RESF-37
R-37
...

I would like to have it sorted by only numbers it is composed of.

I had :

```
select distinct r.type 
from Reference r
order by REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(r.type, '-', ''), 'F', ''), ' ', '')
```

It was enough because at the beginning, only R, - and F were used. Now I would like to have a solution supporting every characters.

I tried :

```
order by cast(r.type as int)
```

but it gives `SQL Error: 1722, SQLState: 42000`

Any idea about how to do it ?

Comment: Even if you get this query working, are you sure the resulting numbers will give you a meaningful sort?

Comment: Yes because there is, R-37, R-47, R-57, R-37F, R-47F, ...